# DDD with nested entities

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I'm trying a project using DDD. I'm confused on how to proceed. Here is a sample of my Entities. Tried to keep it brief.

But I'm struggling with the following

**1.** Update an address on a Person - there are business rules such as the Person must have X number of Address type.

I can grab the address from Person.Addresses and change it, but how would I validate Person is still valid when the changes were on the address?

**2.** If 2 addresses are required on creation. What would be the best way to to initialize the object? There could be more addresses on creation as well.

```
public class Person // AggregateRoot
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid StatusId { get; set; } //FK to Status

   private List<Address> _addresses = new List<Address>();
   public IReadOnlyCollection<Address> Addresses => _addresses.AsReadOnlyList();
   //more

   public void AddAddress(...)
   {
          //Logic
          _addresses.Add(...)
   }
}


public class Status 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //more..
}

public class Address()
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Address1 { get; set; }
   public Guid AddressTypeId { get; set; }//FK to Address Type
}

public class AddressType()
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach here is to control any operations on the child entities via the parent.  In DDD parlance, the two entities working together is an `aggregate` and the `Person` entity is the `aggregate root`.  All operations on the Addresses should be done via the `Person` - this gives the `Person` class the opportunity to enforce the invariants (rules) that apply even across the collection of `Addresses`.

As an example:

```
class Person
{

   void UpdateAddress(Guid addressId, ...updatevalues)
   {
      var address = Addresses.Select(a => a.Id == addressId);
      address.Update(updateValues);
      VerifyAddressesCorrect();
   }
}
```

The code outside the `Person` class should *never* call any methods on the Address directly.

To answer your second question, a common pattern would be to put the rules in a constructor overload, or if that doesn't suit, a static factory method on the `Person` class.  This gives you a lot of flexibility for how you structure the input and what rules you enforce at the time the entity comes into existance.

Personally I like the static factory method because it allows you to give a more meaningful name to what is going on when the class is instantiated.  I try and avoid terms like `Create` because there's usually a more domain oriented term, like `Person.Register()` or `Person.Onboard()`

Similarly, the `.UpdateAddress` method is not great as `Update` is a crud term that doesn't shed much light on the domain - what is actually happening here from the user's/domain perspective?  Sure, sometimes an update is just an update (e.g. a data entry error needs correcting), but it can be a prompt to consider if there is a more meaningful domain concept at play.

Comment: Thanks for helpful insight Chris. I guess where I'm more concerned is how do pass the address type? As there is a decent amount of logic revolving around changing an address based on type. Do I pass in a full AddressType object instead of just a guid in that scenario? Since the guid would not be enough to run logic off of.

Comment: It's hard to be specific without more clarity into your domain. You can pass in an address type object (or other domain entity/valueobject), or even pass in a user input dto. DDD isn't prescriptive about stuff like that- it just says to use words/language from the domain in your code, design your entities/relationships and events by considering a model that will be useful in that domain and be ready to evolve your model as your understanding grows. If you're doing that, then following basic 'code smell' refactoring (e.g. like https://refactoring.guru) will guide you well at the code level.